# Error in a C program

Tags: c

When i want to run a C file its shows an error...
Linker error:undefined symbol _main in module c0.ASM

Comment: I download this program from..http://bcl.comli.eu/download-en.html

Answer (score 5):

<s>You forgot to define `main`. Or you defined it, but forgot to link the object file containing it into the program.</s>

You're compiling a library, not a program. First compile the library using the `Makefile` that comes with it, then write a program to the library's API, then compile that and link it to the library.

Comment: I just download this program from a site..which is http://bcl.comli.eu/download-en.html                     so plz just look at the program and help me out to rum it successfully ..

Comment: @user720101: you can't run it, it's not a program. It's a library. https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Library_%28computing%29

Comment: sorry to say that i don't know how to compile a library and the after facts........so plz help me to do that...

Comment: @user720101: See the documentation on how to compile it